# node.js unzip file. file name is broken

Tags: javascript, node.js, zip, unzip

I tried to unzip the file.

```
let zip = new AdmZip('./sample.zip')
zip.extractAllTo(path, true)
```

but,the name of the contents file is Japanese.
So file name is broken.

```
���̑�-�T�|�[�g�O
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `extractEntryTo` allows you to specify the target path.

Comment: Unzip is successful. but file name is broken.

Comment: Looking at the `adm-zip` code for [`extractAllTo`](https://github.com/cthackers/adm-zip/blob/master/adm-zip.js#L366-L390) it appears that it uses `entry.entryName.toString()` instead of `entry.entryName.toString('utf8')` which may be the source of the issue. Consider using the [`zip`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zip) package which supports filenames with UTF-8 characters.

Comment: @spex If I want to implement unzip in `zip` package, what kind of code would it be?